# Why my Kubernetes Services are not connecting?

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 services running on Kubernetes (front, nodejs server and a mysql database). The first service is of type `load Balancer` and runs the front-end (angular) of the web app with an external ip address. The second service runs the nodejs server  with type `ClusterIP` and the third service is of type `ClusterIP` and runs mysql.

The connection between the nodejs service and the database works perfect.
The problem is the connection between the front service and the nodejs service in Kubernetes. When the nodejs service type is `ClusterIP` the API calls are this way (and doesnt work: throw me time out):

```
export class TareasService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTareas(){
    return this.http.get('http://<NODEJS-SERVICE-CLUSTERIP>:3000/api/tareas/'); 
  }

  getTarea(id:string){
    return this.http.get('http://<NODEJS-SERVICE-CLUSTERIP>:3000/api/tareas/'+ id);
  }

  saveTarea(tarea:Tarea){
    return this.http.post('http://<NODEJS-SERVICE-CLUSTERIP>:3000/api/tareas',tarea);
  }
...
```

But if I change the type of the nodejs kubernetes service to `load Balancer` and set the API calls this way:

```
export class TareasService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTareas(){
    return this.http.get('http://<NODEJS-SERVICE-EXTERNALIP>:3000/api/tareas/'); 
  }

  getTarea(id:string){
    return this.http.get('http://<NODEJS-SERVICE-EXTERNALIP>:3000/api/tareas/'+ id);
  }

  saveTarea(tarea:Tarea){
    return this.http.post('http://<NODEJS-SERVICE-EXTERNALIP>:3000/api/tareas',tarea);
  }
...
```

It works perfectly. The documentation says that the Cluster IP is accessible from anything inside the cluster, which is the case. Why doesnt work? Is there any other option that doesn't expose the service?

List of the services when its working:

[image: kubectl get svc]

--edit:

The docker image of the node js server:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/build
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

and the yaml as `ClusterIP` by default:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs-poc
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: my-image
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs-poc
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Comment: Try using the clusterip service name instead of the ip.

Comment: @RakeshGupta I tried that and also with the internal pods ip

Comment: The only other possibility that I can think of if the services are in different namespaces, but that does look like the case from the service output in your question

Comment: if you use the ip, the namespace doesnt matter. If you use the service name and therefore the kubernetes dns resolver, then the namespace matters. You can do servicename.namespace if they are in a different namespace.

Comment: Note that you dont need to redact your CLUSTER-IPs, those are private ips, no one can do anything with them unlike the external ips.

Comment: They are in the same namespace. The default namespace (i did `kubectl --namespace=default get svc`)

Comment: Presumed your nodejs server is listening to 0.0.0.0 and **not** localhost? Can you post the nodejs service spec to your question.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how you set up your cluster and provide nodejs service spec?

Comment: And yet, how did you setup your cluster (cloud provider, etc)?  Could you provide the output of ´kubectl get service nodejs-poc -o json´ command when you can´t reach nodejs?